# SFINAE to enable nontemplate member function

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

This is probably a duplicate, but I just can't find one where the OP clearly has the same problem I'm having.
I have a class, and I'm trying to enable `operator-` only if the class template parameter is not an unsigned type.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
struct A {
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_unsigned<T>::value,A>::type operator-() {return {};}
};

int main() {
    A<unsigned> a=a;
}
```

Unfortunately, this produces a compiler error any time I instantiate it with an unsigned type as shown.

```
main.cpp:5:29: error: no type named 'type' in 'std::enable_if<false, A<unsigned int> >'; 'enable_if' cannot be used to disable this declaration
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_unsigned<T>::value,A>::type operator-() {return {};}
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:9:17: note: in instantiation of template class 'A<unsigned int>' requested here
    A<unsigned> a=a;
                ^
```

Well, I can clearly see that `enable_if` is not going to work here.  One vaguely similar question mentioned I can use inheritance and template specialization to work around this, but... is there really no better way?

Comment: The problem here is that all member function *declarations* are instantiated when the class template is (implicitly) instantiated. Therefore, all member declarations must be well-formed when instantiating the class template.

Comment: Hmm why not just introduce this function for all specializations but use a `static_assert` inside? SFINAE is only required when you want a fall-back, but maybe that's not necessary here.

Comment: @dyp.... well that does seem obvious in hindsight doesn't it?  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99204410f0e80491 That does seem like the best answer for my code, thought maybe not this question as posted :(

Comment: The only problem with such an approach is that "it lies" when using "reflection light" (traits / decltype+SFINAE checks): It'll always say "`operator-` exists" even if it cannot be called.

Comment: @dyp: Also, if a template class is explicitly instantiated in a cpp file: `template struct A<unsigned>;`, it instantiates that function and produces the error :(

Comment: True, but won't e.g. the StdLib classes have the same problem (e.g. a vector of noncoyable elements) with explicit instantiation?

Comment: @dyp: oh, [so they do!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/148bf262b2bb6ac9)

Comment: @MooingDuck, but putting `extern` in front of the explicit instantiation does not give any errors. `extern template class std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>;`  So, implicit instantiation is `extern`? Now I'm no longer sure what use `extern` explicit instantiation is - does it do anything beyond checking the template `vector` (and `unique_ptr`) exists?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: You're guess is mostly correct: `extern` explicit instantiation _tells_ the compiler that the class is explicitly instantiated elsewhere, so it doesn't have to instantiate anything for this file.  So yeah, it just checks that `vector` exists.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem once. Turns out there can't be a substitution failure since the default template argument doesn't depend on a template parameter from the function template. You have to have a template argument defaulted to the enclosing template type, like this:

```c++
template<typename U = T,
         class = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_unsigned<U>::value, U>::type>
A operator-() { return {}; }
```

Comment: default template arguments are only allowed on a class template

Comment: @v.oddou Not since C++11.

Comment: Oh, ok, then a little edit to stipulate that, and we're good :)

Answer (score 4):

A bit long for a comment: You can also use a free function, even for unary operators.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
struct A {
};

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_unsigned<T>::value,A<T>>::type
operator-(A<T>) {return {};}

int main() {
    A<signed> b;
    -b; // ok

    A<unsigned> a;
    -a; // error
}
```

This doesn't introduce a member function template for each class template.

---

Here's how you can befriend it:

```
template<class T>
class A {
    int m;

public:
    A(T p) : m(p) {}

    template<class U>
    friend
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_unsigned<U>::value,A<U>>::type
    operator-(A<U>);
};

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_unsigned<T>::value,A<T>>::type
operator-(A<T> p) {return {p.m};}

int main() {
    A<signed> b(42);
    -b; // ok

    A<unsigned> a(42);
    //-a; // error
}
```

You can (should) forward-declare that function template, though.

Comment: Well, that's... simple and straightforward O.O

Comment: interestingly, a friend function doesn't seem to cut it

Comment: But with this I can't access the private members, and there's no way to `friend` it

Comment: @MooingDuck You may have "free function" `operator-` use a function object `F` (e.g. `operator-(A<T> a) { return F()(a); }`) that is a `friend` of `A` (i.e. `template<class T> struct A { friend F; };`.

Answer (score 3):

One possible way is introducing a dummy template parameter:

```
template<class T>
struct A {
    template<
       typename D = int,
       typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_unsigned<T>::value, D>::type
    >
    A operator-() {return {};}
};
```

Comment: trying to compile in vs2013 with "A<signed> b = -b;" crashes CL.exe

Comment: @wonkorealtime VC++ has big problems with SFINAE. [Even in VS2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx).

Comment: `template` above is ill-formed, maybe 14.6/8: "If no valid specialization can be generated for a template, and that template is not instantiated, the template is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.": but `&A<unsigned>::operator-<unsigned,void>` or something?  Is there a way to say that, and does it matter?

Comment: @Yakk I don't know. You mean after `A` is instantiated e.g. with `T=int` (not unsigned), then there is no valid specialization for `operator-`? But then, as you say, `operator-<unsigned,void>` is a valid specialization, only we don't intend to really use it, right?

Comment: @iavr yep, but I was unsure if it was reschable (does that syntax work?).  Evrn if not, probably still legal.  So, nevermind.

Comment: @Yakk Yes, it works. I use it a lot on default constructors, because these have no input parameters and no return type, so there isn't anywhere else to place an `enable_if`.

Comment: @iavr In those cases, if you cannot pick the valid specialization, does that mean thr valid specialization exists or does it not?  Probably it exists, despite being unreachable. Does thr body have to be valid?  Unsure.

Comment: @Yakk An example is [here](https://github.com/iavr/ivl2/blob/master/include/ivl/root/core/tuple/store/tuple.hpp) [line 75], where the default constructor of a tuple is enabled iff all elements of types `E...` are default-constructible. This works in practice. If this constructor is valid, it can be instantiated by attempting to default-construct such a tuple, even though you can't explicitly specify its template arguments. So, is this well-formed? I'm not sure. D's `static if` so much solves all these problems...

Answer (score 1):

There is a long way using inheritance:

```
template <class T>
struct A;

template <class T, bool = std::is_unsigned<T>::value>
struct MinusOperator
{
    A<T> operator-()
    {
        A<T>* thisA = static_cast<A<T>*>(this);
        // use thisA instead of this to get access to members of A<T>
    }
};

template <class T>
struct MinusOperator<T, true> {};

template <class T>
struct A : MinusOperator<T>
{
    friend struct MinusOperator<T>;
};
```

Comment: I think this would be better of if `A` inherted from `MinusOperator<std::is_unsigned<T>::value>`, and then specialize `template<bool is_unsigned> struct MinusOperator<true>`

Comment: @MooingDuck I inattentively read your question, sorry. You want to disable `operator-` for all unsigned types. But your fix to my solution is not suitable because there is no template parameter `T` in it.